# How to convert byte to binary in java?

Tags: java, binary, byte

I have attempted convert from 10000101 to -123 by code

```
byte sum = (byte) (Integer.valueOf(10000101, 2) & 0xffff) ";
```

now I don't know how to convert back from -123 to 10000101.

Any suggestions about using java API to do conversion?

Comment: Are you aware of the `toBinaryString` method of the `Integer` class?

Comment: @community.. it is not the same question.. OP here asks to convert a byte to a binary string.. it's a completely different question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit the David Wallace comment, you can do it with this code:

```
    String fromByteToString = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(sum & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
    System.out.println(fromByteToString);
```

with `sum & 0xFF` you do the bitwise AND operation:

```
-123 = 11111111111111111111111110000101
0xFF = 00000000000000000000000011111111
res. = 00000000000000000000000010000101
```

Note that the `replace(' ', '0')` is not a must in this case because the binary result string starts (10000101) with 1.